# Access a virtual host on a server in VirtualBox directly

Tags: virtualbox, dns, virtualhost, dnsmasq

The server: *Ubuntu 10.10 Server* as guest in a *VirtualBox* (IP 192.168.178.91).

Simple Question: I want to access a virtual host named 'example.server' from outside my virtual box by simply using a browser and an address like http://example.server.
The whole thing should be realized by using *DNSMasq*.
Thx. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you configure Virtualbox to use bridged networking

[image: bridge]

Next you install dnsmasq on your dns server. I assume this is Ubuntu with an ip address of 192.168.178.10 , adjust accordingly

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

You then add your virtualbox server into `/etc/hosts` on the dns (dnsmasq) server

```
# Graphical
gksu gedit /etc/hosts

# Command line
sudo -e /etc/hosts
```

Add in your server

```
192.168.178.91 example.server www.example.server
```

You then point your clients to use your dns (dnsmasq) server for dns. You can do this with network manager, put `192.168.178.10` in as the dns server.

[image: dns]

Comment: Yap, my problem was, that I pointet to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts file, not 192.168.178.91. Formerly, I had a webserver directly on my pc - not virtualized via *VirtualBox* and there it was correct. Thanks for your help! :)